# Attempt to set model object on null model of component

Tags: wicket

I'm new to Wicket, but googling this problem didn't give me anything that made sense.  So I'm hoping someone in SO can help.

I have a SiteChoice object that extends Form, and a SiteList object that extends 
DropDownChoice.  My  SiteChoice class looks like:

```
  public class SiteChoice extends Form {
     public SiteChoice(String id) {
        super(id);

    addSiteDropDown();
     }

  private void addSiteDropDown() {

    ArrayList<DomainObj> siteList = new ArrayList<DomainObj>();
   // add objects to siteList

    ChoiceRenderer choiceRenderer = new ChoiceRenderer<DomainObj>("name", "URL");

    this.add(new SiteList("siteid",siteList,choiceRenderer));
   }
}
```

Then I simply add my SiteChoice object to my Page object a la:

```
    SiteChoice form = new SiteChoice("testform");
    add(form);
```

My Wicket template has:

When I bring up the page, it renders fine -- the drop-down list is correctly rendered.  When I hit Submit, I get this strange error:

```
WicketMessage: Method onFormSubmitted of interface 
  org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at component   
 [MarkupContainer [Component id = fittest]] threw an exception

Root cause:

   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to set model object on null 
model of component: testform:siteid
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.setDefaultModelObject(Component.java:3033)
    at
  org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.updateModel(FormComponent.java:1168)
   at 
 [snip]
```

I can't figure out what is null.  It rendered fine, so it found the objects.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, you're not showing the code for your SiteList class, but what's happening is that something -- almost certainly the dropdown -- doesn't have a model. So when wicket calls, essentially, `dropdown.getModel().setModelObject( foo ) ;` it gets a null pointer exception.

My suggestion is this, following the old OO rule of thumb to *prefer composition to inheritance*. Your `SiteChoice` and `SiteList` classes don't seem to add much, and they're making your errors harder to debug.

Instead, just add a DropDownChoice to your form:

```
 form.add( new DropDownChioce( "siteid", 
                               new Model<DomainObject>(), 
                               new ChoiceRenderer<DomainObj>("name", "URL") );
```

That's more concise too,