# Attempt to set model object on null model of component: DropDownChoice

Tags: java, wicket, dropdownchoice

I'm using a wicket Wizard to let the user take multiple steps for a registration.
But Somehow I get this error:

> Last cause: Attempt to set model object on null model of component: wizard:form:view:sprachenDrop
>   WicketMessage: Method onFormSubmitted of interface org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at [Form [Component id = form]] on component [Form [Component id = form]] threw an exception

And this snippet from the stack trace:

> Root cause:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to set model object on null model of component: wizard:form:view:sprachenDrop
>        at org.apache.wicket.Component.setDefaultModelObject(Component.java:3038)
>        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.setModelObject(FormComponent.java:1577)
>        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.updateModel(FormComponent.java:1098)
>        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$FormModelUpdateVisitor.component(Form.java:230)
>        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$FormModelUpdateVisitor.component(Form.java:200)

Refering to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452310/attempt-to-set-model-object-on-null-model-of-component) I tried to create a class to hold the information I need, but it didn't work, I took [this tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/DropDownChoice+Examples) as basic. From Wicket's help itself I tried [this code](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?0&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.Index&source=DropDownChoicePage.java) and thus created an IClusterable class to hold the information. The error was still the same. Since `DropDownChoice` comes with a constructor able to hold a List as Model I thought that my code should work.

```
public class StepPersoenlicheDaten  extends WizardStep{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private RequiredTextField<String> name, vorname, strasse, ort, telefonNr;
    private DropDownChoice<String> korrespondenzsprache;
    private List<String> sprachen = new ArrayList<String>();


    public StepPersoenlicheDaten(WizardModel model) {
        super(new ResourceModel("daten.title"), new ResourceModel("daten.summary"));
        init(model);
        java.util.Collections.addAll(sprachen, "Deutsch","English","Français","Italiano");

        add(name = new RequiredTextField<String>("name", Model.of("")));
        add(vorname = new RequiredTextField<String>("vorname",  Model.of("")));
        add(strasse = new RequiredTextField<String>("strasse",  Model.of("")));
        add(ort = new RequiredTextField<String>("ort",  Model.of("")));
        add(telefonNr = new RequiredTextField<String>("telefonNr", Model.of("")));
        add(korrespondenzsprache = new DropDownChoice<String>("sprachenDrop", sprachen));
    }
}
```

The error appears when I click the finish (or next) button on the wizard. I don't know what else I could try to fix it.

Edit:

```
IModel<Collection<? extends String>> langs = Model.of(sprachen);
add(korrespondenzsprache = new DropDownChoice<String>("sprachenDrop", langs));
```

Was not accepted.

Comment: You have to set model for Dropdownchoice.

Comment: A Model that holds the List or a Model that holds the choice?

Comment: i don't know why you are setting model like this? Dropdownchoice is String  you are setting model Collection? at the same time how this StepPersoenlicheDaten will call under page? i have many confusion? why don't you create variable for the dropdown add getter/setter then set propertymodel?

Comment: model should be choice.

Comment: Add  private  String sprachenDrop; include getter/setter.then add(korrespondenzsprache = new DropDownChoice<String>("sprachenDrop", new PropertyModel(this,"sprachenDrop"),sprachen)); It Should work.

Comment: I tried something simular to this earlier, although it didn't work. But now I understand what the mistake was :) Would you like to change the comment to an answear, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a local string like 
`private String sprachenDrop;` and add getters/setters. Then add:

```
add(korrespondenzsprache = new DropDownChoice<String>("sprachenDrop", 
new PropertyModel(this, "sprachenDrop"), sprachen));
```

It Should work.

Comment: That works but now you're making your page into your model object. Please don't do that, that is bad form. It would be better to make add a private field `private IModel<String> spracheModel;` and do

`spracheModel = Model.of((String)null);
add(korrespondenzsprache = new DropDownChoice<String>    ("sprachenDrop", spracheModel, sprachen));`

After form submission `spracheModel.getObject()` would give you the picked language.